# PHP Reset Password with code instead of link

Tags: php, bcrypt, reset-password

Is there anything wrong with emailing a user a randomly generated code rather than a link when they want to change their password.

The procedure would be...

1. User triggers password reset by entering email address
2. Email is checked in DB to be a genuine user
3. Email is sent to that user with a randomly generated code
4. The same code is bcrypt'ed and inserted in the database in a dedicated column
5. User enters the code sent to them by email
6. It is checked against the stored based bcrypt password
7. (If all correct) User is allowed to enter a new password

Comment: Nope, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: The security is the same, it's just a matter of feasibility.

Comment: It's just more of a pain for users to have to copy and paste the code (esp. mobile users).

Answer (score 2):

There is really no difference in terms of security whether it's a code or a link.

All the link does is automatically enter the code and submit the form; the only downside of a link is that some (bad in my opinion) email providers would automatically issue GET requests to all links in emails, in which case what you should do is your link should lead to a page asking to click a button to confirm the reset (issuing a second POST request behind the scenes) so that "accidental" GETs don't trigger the reset.

In terms of security, email isn't the most secure medium as you have no way of enforcing encryption once the mail leaves your email server - if mail servers that happen to relay that email don't support encryption they'll pass the mail unencrypted to the next server, etc.

So assuming you're fine with the mail being potentially unencrypted during transit (not that you can do much about it - maybe using SMS but even that is unencrypted and I'm not really sure which one is harder to intercept), the only security you can enforce is to have the code entry page/link page served only over HTTPS so that an attacker sitting between the user's machine and your server won't be able to intercept it once the user attempts to enter the code or the link.

A good user experience solution is to make your code entry page accept query string parameters to fill in the code automatically if provided (and serve a blank form for the user to fill manually if the parameter is missing) and your email should both contain the (HTTPS) link and the code in case the user can't use the link for some reason.